# Drupal This page can't be displayed. Contact support for additional information

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

Whenever I enter a node body in drupal and the node body contains an "img" tag I get the following error:

[image]

It was not happening earlier and it has just appeared on the site.  How could I fix it?

Comment: disable all modules. Try it again.  if you get the error then go to reports> logs and get more information on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen an error styled like that from Drupal, so I would recommend looking at other aspects of your server stack. [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917937/browser-security-error-this-page-cant-be-displayed-due-to-a-security-violatio) had a similar-looking screenshot that turned out to be firewall-related.

Comment: It did turn out to be the Firewall issue. Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing this same issue using the fckeditor. I see this error whenever i insert an image my editor. I would like to know what exactly in the firewall did you guys get rid of to get this issue fixed? Thanks in advance

Comment: I just had to be on the same network as the host to post content