# Authorize.net gateway: The incident ID is: N/A

Tags: authorize.net

I have a payment page using authorize.net gateway. After payment processing, the return url is not going back to my site.

The page shows this error:

> This page can't be displayed. Contact support for additional information.
>   The incident ID is: N/A.

Also, the url does not return back to my site. It remains on authorize.net.

The coding is fine, because it was working before.  Authorize.net updated some API's recently. After that this happened.

Does anyone know the issue?

#### Code:

```
$form2 = "
<form id='form2' name='form2' method='post' action='".$url."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='payment_type' value='cc' />
    <input type='hidden' name='invoice' value='".$invoice."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='mem_no' value='".$mem_no."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_login' value='".$loginID."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_amount' value='".$amount."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_description' value='".$description."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_invoice_num' value='".$invoice."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_cust_id' value='".$mem_no."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_payment_type' value='cc' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_type' value='AUTH_ONLY' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_fp_sequence' value='".$sequence."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_fp_timestamp' value='".$timeStamp."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_fp_hash' value='".$fingerprint."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_test_request' value='".$testMode."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_show_form' value='PAYMENT_FORM' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_cancel_url' value='https://www.m.sassybling.com/order_ship.php' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_cancel_url_text' value='Cancel & Return to Sassybling' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_point' value='".$point_discount."' /> 
    <input type='hidden' name='x_relay_response' value='TRUE' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_relay_url' value='https://www.m.sassybling.com/order_returnCC.php' />
</form>";
```

Comment: You should post the *rendered* HTML produced by the PHP above so we can try to duplicate the issue. The odds are one of those values in invalid.

Answer (score 0):

it was a firewall issue. The issue was related to Imperva, which sits in front on the server, monitoring traffic and blocking "threatening" requests.

[Browser Security Error: "This page can't be displayed due to a security violation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917937/browser-security-error-this-page-cant-be-displayed-due-to-a-security-violatio)